# Diagnostic plots from ARIMA() function

Tags: r, time-series, xts, arima

I have a time series of `returns`. I found out the optimal c(p,d,q) of an ARIMA(p,d,q) (I called it `return.order`) so that I finally got:

```
returns.arima <- prima(returns, order=returns.order)
```

This is not a `lm` file so I don't get the following diagnostic plots after computing `plot(returns.arima)`:

[image]

but instead I get just the inverse unit roots:

[image]

So my questions are the following:

1. Is there a way to maybe convert my format to the `lm` one, so that I can produce this output easily?
2. If not, let's say I managed to get the residuals QQ-Plot through the following:

`qqnorm(residuals.arima)`

however, I didn't manage to find a way to report the outliers as in the first picture I posted.
Somebody knows how to do it?

3. What about Residual vs leverage, scale location and Cook's Distance Plots?

Comment: yeah, you could most certainly write out the closed form equation for the model, if you know your p,d, and q parameters. might need to write it out by hand to simplify it first... there's also the `sarima` package in R, which allows you to specify the parameters you need (p,d,q) and then gives summary output for the model, which includes hypothesis tests for importance of terms... I imagine it would also give residuals, which can be used to make plots.